# Logging In and out Interceptor messages with log4j in CXF

Tags: java, web-services, rest, log4j, cxf

I am trying to redirect LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor messages of my rest webservices from console to file using log4j as below,

**cxf.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

        <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">

            <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                <ref bean="Service" />
            </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

            <jaxrs:features>
                <cxf:logging />
            </jaxrs:features>

        </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />

    </beans>
```

**org.apache.cxf.Logger file**

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

**log4j.properties**

```
        # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

    ## more informations
    # http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html
    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\ServiceLog.txt
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Addtional details,

CXF 3.1.4 and Java 7

[image]

Here i am receiving both the messages in console but it is not writing in the file.

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me here..

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you put in your `org.apache.cxf.Logger` file the one line text

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

Also, make sure it is part of the WAR classpath, hence it should end up under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` once your WAR is properly packaged.

Finally, looking at your log4j configuration file, you missed to set the CXF logger level at `INFO` as below:

```
log4j.appender.org.apache.cxf.Threshold=INFO
```

Try to add this line at the end of your log4j configuration.

Comment: I have corrected in org.apache.cxf.Logger file and added the above line in log4j configuration file but it doesn't helped me out.. FYI, I am just running it in eclipse, so in this case what i shown above is right structure to place org.apache.cxf.Logger (META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger)?

Answer (score 3):

As you can read on [Apache CXF - Debbuging and Logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingLog4jInsteadofjava.util.logging) CXF uses Java SE Logging, but you can change the logging implementation:

> As noted above, CXF uses the `java.util.logging` package ("Java SE Logging") by default. But it is possible to switch CXF to instead use Log4J. This is achieved through the use of configuration files. There are two options to bootstrapping CXF logging and each is listed below:
>
> - Add the following system property to the classpath from which CXF is initialized:
>
>   `-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`
> - Add the file `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` to the classpath and make sure it contains the following content:
>
>   `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`

You have to change the contents of your `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` file from `org.apache.cxf.Logger` to `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`

Answer (score 0):

Yes here is the solution, We can do it by two ways as below,

1. By configuring the below system variable in classpath

   -Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger

For reference- This is how i configured in eclipse

[image]

2. By placing the **org.apache.cxf.Logger** file under **WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/cxf/**

Comment: Great, well done. This is because you specify it directly as a parameter, the solution to use a file should as well work, but you should make sure the file is in the application classpath, hence the /META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger file should be located under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger. Can you give it a try without the -D parameter?

Comment: Interesting.. I tried and it is working well in this way too..  So, both the options works great..

Comment: Cool, I'll update my answer anyway with this further detail, just in case for the future, even if not accepted as final answer. Thanks for having tried it out btw.

Comment: Actually it was already part of the answer, no need for update.